# Skipping iterations in loops in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, loops

I am trying to make this loop skip 20 pixels and then draw the next box. I draw the boxes side by side perfectly the way I coded it. But I cannot figure out how to make it skip pixels. I think this is a simple addition but I cannot see it. I have googled other for loops as well, but I cannot pick out what I am missing, and I have read a few books I have as well.
here is what I have:

```
Public Class Form1

    Const CellWidth As Integer = 50
    Const cellHeight As Integer = 50
    Const xOffset As Integer = -20
    Const yOffset As Integer = 25
    Private DEFAULT_BACKCOLOR As Color = Color.White

    Public Sub DrawBoard()      
        Dim location As New Point
        '---draws the boxes
        For row As Integer = 1 To 9
            For col As Integer = 1 To 9
                location.X = col * (CellWidth + 1) + xOffset
                location.Y = row * (cellHeight + 1) + yOffset
                Dim lbl As New Label
                With lbl
                    .Name = col.ToString() & row.ToString()
                    .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
                    .Location = location
                    .Width = CellWidth
                    .Height = cellHeight
                    .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                    .BackColor = DEFAULT_BACKCOLOR
                    .Font = New Font(.Font, .Font.Style Or FontStyle.Bold)
                    .Tag = "1"                   
                End With
                Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
            Next            
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DrawBoard()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It looks like you are subtracting 20 pixels from the x value each iteration.  Did you mean to add 20?  Also, you might want to say (col * CellWidth) + 1 when setting location.X and Y.

Comment: thanks for the response, I will try these changes, the offset just moves the beginning start draw area for the for loop

Comment: But you are moving it by the width of the cell + 1 already (with my second change), then subtracting 20.  Not sure why you are doing that.  If you want a 20 pixel buffer between each image, you need to add 20.